# Hugo toha template failed to extract shortcode

Tags: github-pages, hugo

I'just cloned the Hugo toha template site from `https://github.com/hugo-toha/hugo-toha.github.io` I´ve tried to run it using the code `hugo server -t toha -w` and I've got the following error: `hugo-toha.github.io/content/notes/bash/basic/index.bn.md:13:1": failed to extract shortcode: template for shortcode "note" not found`

Since I've just cloned from the official repo it should be working, if I run it locally and it should be like in the site `https://hugo-toha.github.io/` someone knows whats happening ?
Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a 'note.html' in your 'layouts/shortcodes' directory this will be 'fixed'.